# How convert value in time format? objective c

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I am making an alarm clock in which i use three text field in which user enter value like as 9:10:AM. Now i want to convert the values of all three text filed in to second and then set notification for that time on next day. The problem is that i convert it into second and how set date and time for next day for notification?
Another problem is how calculate time difference between current time set time?
For example i set time in text field is 9:00:am And current time is 6:00:pm. Now how set local-notification for set time of next day?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at NSDateFormatter?

Comment: Do you really think this is an answer? Post this as a comment, or add more context to the answer.

Comment: Sure. Would do that next time. comments is something that is just enabled for me. I think it is based on points or something.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the date of next day of any particular day you can use this method on any NSDate object which you have and need its next day's date.

`newDate [refDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400];`

Here newDate will be the date exactly after 24 hrs from refDate. Both of them need to be essentially NSDate objects. And this method will also handle all validations like if it is the ending day of the month or it is a leap year and end of February, or any such validation. You will be a perfect date exactly 24 hrs after refDate.

And if you with to schedule a local notification on this next day's time than you can directly do it because it takes NSDate object only. But make sure you use proper NSDateFormatter.